# flutter not appling padding

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

```
   Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 30.0,
                            backgroundImage:NetworkImage('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fife/AAWUweVJ6fa0mu8MKDVxZb4AyDAY26PRa78SPnSUIJlo9fB6gnwWgQI-ARzrhqg2Z7X82PGJ_3VhJF385aL85wlg83NShyZcM_D-PdfabWVsu_q8nH4M9fWHp2KEolKaiuZpyXry_M02Zo--wJ0L8qMdeekyAjsBQhn7Pp7kEf6wOZt9gSrAFV6x3C2f93jiBLLTEvFGeeq3_nvQ7RqudNh4luONe-6JP5bUv1fAFasE4YYQ2VHEmInxCLv8Vr0zQY_3zhdFR-otkayQ8rrAr3S8tXN3RCbQiFRn8BYJRS1pKB-FGMtzc-cxPB0x0xVaLI0B3UrijPIBqPk52qHqlYeOVjF4OAiVFviju2I6rc2gelX-vF82cy-iSYU94qmJZtyidaHex5biPZtf7WNH2E6nKmcScFSVs1xf9_eRn4yhJjdTAhsiJPMacmGUIfr52oAXK0Ur6U5hGrnghHpQZahUKENn1KmJ1JuUSGWMBp8I5cRldSYCcaD65-jjSqgBMcPA_9KrKYawvcsinrkKLWZe1oeIsHZzmsyMrJt3ivl77T8zxPbPXUbFz81ZJbcAyFzGVePZt6s1GEW8ibRO7H0rB_AULdQ1m3PzHaL3wR0PSYjqVoaRYEtplqvKTHitLFF55X2Md_zhQiH-GyGx0-fIX2qx4X6jo31A1wmO5-xF18zDKhNcKxYpVm9SthtAmqUaXPDwb0HYam0OXRQsx2g6yrsgwav9hd0GoPH3vNU69E7T3g=s83-c'),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                      ),
                      Row(children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10,bottom: 30), child:Text("Ammar Mohib \n",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)),

                      ],),
                      Row(children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 50,bottom: 30), child:Text("message",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)),

                      ],),
                    ],
                  ),
```

[image]

This is my code, I want to give the padding from the right side to the second text wigdet, I want to set the second text widget like first text widget

[image]

I want like this

Comment: Do you want to insert all of this into a line spaced between text widgets?

Comment: Attach screenshot of your result and show what you want to make.

Comment: @SergeyK. I adde image, I want second text like first text

Comment: do you want both text in same line

Comment: @JahidulIslam I now added the picture, I want like that

Comment: i edited my answer please have look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this....

```
Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fife/AAWUweVJ6fa0mu8MKDVxZb4AyDAY26PRa78SPnSUIJlo9fB6gnwWgQI-ARzrhqg2Z7X82PGJ_3VhJF385aL85wlg83NShyZcM_D-PdfabWVsu_q8nH4M9fWHp2KEolKaiuZpyXry_M02Zo--wJ0L8qMdeekyAjsBQhn7Pp7kEf6wOZt9gSrAFV6x3C2f93jiBLLTEvFGeeq3_nvQ7RqudNh4luONe-6JP5bUv1fAFasE4YYQ2VHEmInxCLv8Vr0zQY_3zhdFR-otkayQ8rrAr3S8tXN3RCbQiFRn8BYJRS1pKB-FGMtzc-cxPB0x0xVaLI0B3UrijPIBqPk52qHqlYeOVjF4OAiVFviju2I6rc2gelX-vF82cy-iSYU94qmJZtyidaHex5biPZtf7WNH2E6nKmcScFSVs1xf9_eRn4yhJjdTAhsiJPMacmGUIfr52oAXK0Ur6U5hGrnghHpQZahUKENn1KmJ1JuUSGWMBp8I5cRldSYCcaD65-jjSqgBMcPA_9KrKYawvcsinrkKLWZe1oeIsHZzmsyMrJt3ivl77T8zxPbPXUbFz81ZJbcAyFzGVePZt6s1GEW8ibRO7H0rB_AULdQ1m3PzHaL3wR0PSYjqVoaRYEtplqvKTHitLFF55X2Md_zhQiH-GyGx0-fIX2qx4X6jo31A1wmO5-xF18zDKhNcKxYpVm9SthtAmqUaXPDwb0HYam0OXRQsx2g6yrsgwav9hd0GoPH3vNU69E7T3g=s83-c'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Ammar Mohib",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "message",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Expanded( child: Column(  ...  ) )

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (separaterContext, index) {
          return const Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
            indent: 70.0,
            endIndent: 10.0,
            thickness: 0.2,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (listViewContext, index) {
          return ListTile(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            leading: const CircleAvatar(
              radius: 30.0,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fife/AAWUweVJ6fa0mu8MKDVxZb4AyDAY26PRa78SPnSUIJlo9fB6gnwWgQI-ARzrhqg2Z7X82PGJ_3VhJF385aL85wlg83NShyZcM_D-PdfabWVsu_q8nH4M9fWHp2KEolKaiuZpyXry_M02Zo--wJ0L8qMdeekyAjsBQhn7Pp7kEf6wOZt9gSrAFV6x3C2f93jiBLLTEvFGeeq3_nvQ7RqudNh4luONe-6JP5bUv1fAFasE4YYQ2VHEmInxCLv8Vr0zQY_3zhdFR-otkayQ8rrAr3S8tXN3RCbQiFRn8BYJRS1pKB-FGMtzc-cxPB0x0xVaLI0B3UrijPIBqPk52qHqlYeOVjF4OAiVFviju2I6rc2gelX-vF82cy-iSYU94qmJZtyidaHex5biPZtf7WNH2E6nKmcScFSVs1xf9_eRn4yhJjdTAhsiJPMacmGUIfr52oAXK0Ur6U5hGrnghHpQZahUKENn1KmJ1JuUSGWMBp8I5cRldSYCcaD65-jjSqgBMcPA_9KrKYawvcsinrkKLWZe1oeIsHZzmsyMrJt3ivl77T8zxPbPXUbFz81ZJbcAyFzGVePZt6s1GEW8ibRO7H0rB_AULdQ1m3PzHaL3wR0PSYjqVoaRYEtplqvKTHitLFF55X2Md_zhQiH-GyGx0-fIX2qx4X6jo31A1wmO5-xF18zDKhNcKxYpVm9SthtAmqUaXPDwb0HYam0OXRQsx2g6yrsgwav9hd0GoPH3vNU69E7T3g=s83-c'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            title: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Ammar Mohib",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Text(
                  "10:10 AM",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                const Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: const Text(
                    "99+",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 9.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]